# Remove duplicates and sort rows

Tags: excel, vba

I have two separate problems but they may have the same cause.

I first need to delete all duplicated rows of a Sheet. Column A contains an index value, which is imported as a text value so "1", "2"... etc.

I searched and got this line of code:

```
VarAnzahlZeilen = 50 '(actually calculated values but they are correct (F8))
VarAnzahlSpalten =50 
     Worksheets("Filter").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(VarAnzahlZeilen, VarAnzahlSpalten)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header _
        :=xlNo
```

Nothing happens, all duplicated rows are still in the sheet.

Same with the next line of code which should sort the remaining rows:

```
Worksheets("Filter").Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, VarAnzahlSpalten)).Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Header:=xlNo
```

Nothing happens.

A test msgbox right there, is shown and the worksheet/Range combo is also correct (I can change values).

---

The whole row would be a duplicate since the import works that way but since the index is in column A, I choose this as the indicator for a duplicate.

This is my current version:

```
With Worksheets("Filter")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(VarAnzahlZeilen, VarAnzahlSpalten)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(VarAnzahlZeilen, VarAnzahlSpalten)).Sort Key1:=Range("A2"), Header:=xlNo
End With
```

Comment: To remove duplicates, have you tried using [Range.RemoveDuplicates method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Range.RemoveDuplicates)?

Comment: What do you define as "duplicate"? In you code, it would identify duplicates by Column 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always qualifiy your range references up to sheet object, otherwise ActiveSheet reference would be implicitly assumed:

```
With Worksheets("Filter")
    .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(VarAnzahlZeilen, VarAnzahlSpalten)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
End With
```

The dot in “.Cells()” is referencing the object referenced in “With” statement(i.e. “Worksheets("Filter")“)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Unfortunatly i dont really get it. sry iam new to vba. I should alwys use the "With" when i use range to avoid confusen which sheet i mean?

I implemented it like you said (unfortunatly without success :/) see main post